# 'display' property by slideToggle still remains after I resize the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
nav > ul {display: flex; margin-right: 20px; height: 100%;}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
      nav > ul {position: absolute; display: none; top: 60px; width: 100%; height: 360px;}
}
</style>

<script>
$('nav .menu a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('nav ul').slideToggle(100);
    });
</script>
```

'display: none' or 'display: block' given to 'nav ul' by 'slideToggle' still remains after I resize window-width back to bigger than 800px. So the original 'flex' option at default doesn't work.
I don't know what the problem is. Any comments will be appreciated.

I hope this is so called "minimal example":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <style>

    body {position: relative; background-color: #999;}
    /* nav */
    nav {position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 60px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;}
    nav > ul {display: flex; margin-right: 20px; height: 100%;}

    nav > ul > li {height: 100%; width: 90px;}

    nav > ul > li > a {color: #eee; text-decoration: none; display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center;}
    nav > ul > li > .a-active {color: #000; text-decoration: underline; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);}
    nav > .menu {content: ''; width: 70px; height: 100%; margin-right: 10px; display: none;}
    nav > .menu > a {display: block; width: 70px; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;}
    nav > .menu > a > .bar {content: ''; width: 40px; height: 5px; border-radius: 2px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); margin-top: 7px;}
    nav > .menu > a > .bar:first-child {margin-top: 16px;}
    nav > .menu > a:hover > .bar {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);}

    @media (max-width: 800px) {
      nav > ul {position: absolute; display: none; top: 60px; width: 100%; height: 360px;}
      nav > ul > li {width: 100%; height: 60px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); font-size: 25px;}
      nav > .menu {display: block;}
    }


  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <h1>Exercise 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="a-active" href="#content1">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#content2">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#content3">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#content4">Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#content5">Five</a></li>
      <li><a href="#content6">Six</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>

    $('nav .menu a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('nav ul').slideToggle(100);
    });

    /* MY SOLUTION BUT NOT SATISFYING :(
    $(window).resize(function() {
      if(window.innerWidth > 800){
        $('nav ul').css('display', 'flex');
      } else if (window.innerWidth <= 800){
        $('nav ul').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
    */

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: either make it important in the CSS or add a resize vent handler that removes the display in the style attribute

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Could you please create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I just added a minimal example you can actually try.